# C# express edition 2012 report viewer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, express, report-viewer2010

i have problem  to use report viewer in  my application i using C# express edition 2012 and report viewer 2010 distributed and report Builder 2.0 and sql server 2012 express edition
is their any one how solve this case before because i try any  solution  on internet and doesn't success

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293179/report-viewer-for-windows-form